# ASP.NET Textbox AutoPostBack Not Firing

Tags: asp.net

After searching I've found a number of suggestions, but none of them are fixing the issue.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="uid" AutoPostBack="True" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
```

In the properties window, EnableViewState = True for the TextBox ([Suggested here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1198167.aspx)). I am typing a new value into the TextBox and then hitting the Tab key.  Nothing happens nor does the break point at if(IsPostBack...) break.

Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(IsPostBack && uid.Text != "" && pw.Text == "")
        {
            Do stuff
        }
    }
```

UPDATE: Other TextBox setups I've tried:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="uid" Text="" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="UidTextChanged"></asp:TextBox>

protected void UidTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('it works');", true);
    }
```

And

```
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="uid" AutoPostBack="True" Text="" onblur="__doPostBack('','');" OnTextChanged="UidTextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

And

```
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="uid" AutoPostBack="True" Text="" onblur="__doPostBack('','');"></asp:TextBox>
```

Whenever AutoPostBack is set to true, I receive the following error in the browser console:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function
__doPostBack
(anonymous function)"
```

When I have the onblur property set, I receive the exact same error except instead of anonymous function it says onblur.

Comment: Several of these options have worked for me...  Can you post your whole aspx page?  It could be something on the page is causing your error, not your text box.

Comment: please see pastebin link below.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a javascript event to the onblur for it.  `onblur='__doPostBack('','');'`

That would cause your text box to cause a postback once it is tabbed out of.

Edit:  It should be " not ' `<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onblur="__doPostBack('','');" />`  Just tried that and it works.  Try removing the `AutoPostBack="True"`

Edit 2:  Base on your pastebin....
`<asp:Button runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="True" ID="submit" Text="Save"
            onclick="SubmitClick"/>`
You can't have an ID of "submit".  Change that to "btnSubmit" and the Javascript solution will work and I bet the Auopostback solution will too.
http://www.xpertdeveloper.com/2012/05/property-submit-of-object-is-not-a-function/ will explain the problem.

Comment: Error in the browser console when I do it that way  "Uncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function __doPostBack
(anonymous function)"

Comment: See the edit I made.  It needs " and not '.  Also remove the `AutoPostBack="True"`

Answer (score 1):

You can add  `OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"` on your textBox

Nota : It's important to set event fire, no just AutoPostBack="true".

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="uid" AutoPostBack="True" Text="" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {  
    .....
}
```

Comment: Other than the Page_Load and TextChanged methods included above, there isn't anything to see.